# Как передать информацию по локальной сети WinSock2?

Tags: c++

Есть сервер он получает данные от клиента

```
AmountRead = recv(ConnSock, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 0);
```

и есть клиент который отправляет данные

```
RetVal = send(ConnSocket, Buffer, AmountToSend, 0);
```

Мне нужно передать информацию, `123` которая храниться в переменной `int i`

Например `int i = 123;`

Как мне ее передать на сервер, более точнее, как мне правильно нужно написать код, в строке `send` и  `recv` что бы передавать и принимать информацию с переменных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще смотрите что можно делать. Вот есть переменная int, её можно передать вместо write или send. Не знаю как в windows, но в линукс в параметре write и send передаётся не char, а void. void * это такой тип, что через него можно отправить что угодно. Например.

```
int i = 4;
send ( ConnSocket, &i, sizeof ( int ) );
```

Так можно передать int. Также можно передать структуру.

```
struct buf {
  int a;
  char m[10];
};
...

    struct buf buf;
    send ( ConnSocket, &buf, sizeof ( struct buf ) );
```

Так мы передаём структуру. Я например передавал структуры по сети, чтобы обмениваться сразу большими данными. ЕЩё как вариант можно сделать так.

```
char buffer[255];
char buffer1[255];
int *i = (int *) &buffer;
*i = 4;
struct buf *buf = (struct buffer *) &buffer1;
buf->a = 4;
send ( ConnSocket, &buffer[0], sizeof ( buffer ) );
send ( COnnSocket, &buffer1[0], sizeof ( buffer1 ) );
```

Здесь sizeof ( buffer ) возвращает размер массива, потому что такой массив можно вычислить. Если бы массиву было выделено в куче, то размер не подчитать так.
В общем я думаю ответил на вопрос.

Comment: В принципе да ответили, я только немного разберусь и поставлю галочку, я сейчас пока изучаю эти технологии с сетью, знаю что мало кто владеет ей в русскоязычном комьюнити.
Поэтому если знаете что то еще пишите буду рад.

Comment: Не знал что структуру можно передать целиком, это может пригодиться.
На стороне сервера прием данных так же пишется, как отправка, верно?

Comment: Можно еще про buffer рассказать что это значит, я так понимаю он хранит в себе память, но как это работает пока сложно найти информацию. Мне бы на понятном гоповсом языке объяснить.

Comment: Можно и на стороне клиента также получать. Но лучше получать массив, а к нему крепить указатель на структуру. Структура только объединяет в себе данные. Это нужно для того, чтобы можно было передать несколько данных в одном параметре. Если хотите, вот мой discord xverizex#7983, можете по си слать туда вопросы, я отвечу если смогу. Если вы указателем на buffer1 соединили структуру, то в buf можно менять значения и они в нужных местах в buffer1 будут меняться. А buffer это массив. То есть 255 байтов, так как число указано 255. char это байт. В си нет строк как в c++.

Comment: В си есть байты, одна буква английская занимает один байт. всего в массиве из 255 байт поместиться 255 букв. Русские буквы в utf-8 кодировке занимают два байта. Поместиться 127 русских букв.

Comment: Понял, а сколько максимально байт я могу передать?

Comment: @zip, ну на моём компе 16384 байта за раз можно принять. А чтобы передать это надо смотреть.